# How can I do live validation for radio button on click event just like we do for textbox on keyup event?

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to know how can i live validate radio button like text box on click event or on key up or press event? Like textbox, when we start typing and if it passes validation, then error message is gone; in the same way i want to implement this functionality for radio button. I have the following code which works only for textbox on keyup event and not for radio buttons -

**HTML -**

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <table border="0" align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th align="right" valign="top"><label for="txtemail">Email ID:</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" size="30" onKeyUp="return isValid();" />
                <span id="erremail"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="right" valign="top"><label>Gender:</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radmale" value="Male" onClick="this.checked; return isValid();" />
                <label for="radmale">Male</label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radfemale" value="Female" onClick="return isValid();" />
                <label for="radfemale">Female</label>
                <span id="errgender"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Register" onClick="return isValid();">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript -**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flag;
function isValid()
{
    flag = true;
    reqdField("txtemail", "erremail", "Email ID is empty");
    isValidEmail("txtemail", "erremail", "Email ID is not valid", /^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z-.]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/);
    checkGender("radmale", "radfemale", "errgender", "Select your gender");
    return flag;
}

// checking all required fields
function reqdField(ctrid, errid, errmsg)
{
    var str = document.getElementById(ctrid).value;
    if(str.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = errmsg;
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = "";
    }
}

// checking is email id valid
function isValidEmail(ctrid, errid, errmsg, validExp)
{
    var email = document.getElementById(ctrid).value;
    if(email.match(validExp) == null)
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = errmsg;
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = "";  
    }
}

// checking is gender selected
function checkGender(ctrid1, ctrid2, errid, errmsg)
{
    var male = document.getElementById(ctrid1);
    var female = document.getElementById(ctrid2);
    if(male.checked == false && female.checked == false)
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = errmsg;
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = "";  
    }
}
</script>
```

Another issue I am facing in this code is regarding reqdField() function. This function does work and only isValidEmail() runs. I only see email is not valid when it is left empty and can not display email id is empty. How can i achieve the same?

Here is the demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/php123/AQU7w/)

Comment: Sorry guys. It couldn't updated at that time. But now its working. Please go and help me.

Comment: Your code works fine. Just change JS Wrap option to `no wrap in body`

Comment: I changed it to - no wrap in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var flag;
function isValid()
{
    flag = true;

    reqdField("txtemail", "erremail", "Email ID is empty");
    isValidEmail("txtemail", "erremail", "Email ID is not valid", /^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z-.]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/);
    checkGender();
    return flag;
}

// checking all required fields
function reqdField(ctrid, errid, errmsg)
{
    var str = document.getElementById(ctrid).value;
    if(str.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = errmsg;
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = "";
         flag = true;
    }
}

// checking is email id valid
function isValidEmail(ctrid, errid, errmsg, validExp)
{
    var email = document.getElementById(ctrid).value;
    if(email.length == 0){
        return;
    }else{
    if(email.match(validExp) == null)
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = errmsg;
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = "";  
         flag = true;
    }
    }
}

// checking is gender selected
function checkGender()
{
    var ctrid1="radmale", ctrid2="radfemale", errid="errgender", errmsg="Select your gender"
    var male = document.getElementById(ctrid1);
    var female = document.getElementById(ctrid2);
    if(male.checked == false && female.checked == false)
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = errmsg;
        return false;
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(errid).innerHTML = "";  
         return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

and html is

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="">
<table border="0" align="center" width="50%" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<th align="right" valign="top"><label for="txtemail">Email ID:</label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" size="30" onKeyUp="return isValid();" />
<span id="erremail"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="right" valign="top"><label>Gender:</label></th>
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="radmale" value="Male" onClick="return checkGender();" /><label for="radmale">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="radfemale" value="Female" onClick="return checkGender();" /><label for="radfemale">Female</label>
<span id="errgender"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Register" onClick="return isValid();"></td>
<td><input type="reset" value="Clear Form"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbandi/4mcHH/6/)

Comment: thanks, but you have solved my second issue - not the first one. I said i wanted to do live validation of radio buttons on click event or some key press event in the same way i did for textbox. When user press submit button and no radio button is checked then if he checks either male or female then error message should be gone. How we do that?

Comment: no frz its not working; plz test my demo on jsfiddle. the radio buttons are not being selected on click.

Comment: Try at your local machine.

Comment: i dont think does that matter. i already tried on my system. its not working. when i said its not working then it meant the live validation of radio button on click is not working. though your solution regarding email field empty validation is working fine.

Comment: thanks, i saw it working on jsfiddle. i also used this strategy in my code and it worked very well. thanks. however i m wondering why do we need to call a separate function checkGender() on click event for both radio buttons - i meant to say why the function isValid() didn't work like it did for textbox validation. i tried to call isValid() for radio button and the radio buttons suddenly stopped to be checked with mouse click. strange! how did it happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
   var set = $(this).attr("name");
   validateRadioSet(set);
});
```

Comment: sorry, it is not useful to me. i also wanted to accomplish the task entirely in vanilla javascript.